# how sohronit page pdf file in byte byte [] and restore back

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I need to parse a PDF file through the pages and load each separately into a `byte[]`. I use the itext library.

I download a file consisting of one page with this code:

```
   public Document addPageInTheDocument(String namePage, MultipartFile pdfData, Long documentId) throws IOException {
      notNull(namePage, INVALID_PARAMETRE);
      notNull(pdfData, INVALID_PARAMETRE);
      notNull(documentId, INVALID_PARAMETRE);
      byte[] in = pdfData.getBytes(); // size file 88747
      Page page = new Page(namePage);
      Document document = new Document();
      document.setId(documentId);
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfData.getBytes()));
      PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
      if (pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages() != 1) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      byte[] transform = pdfDocument.getPage(1).getContentBytes(); // 1907 size page
      page.setPageData(pdfDocument.getPage(1).getContentBytes());
      return addPageInTheDocument(document, page);
  }
```

I'm trying to restore the file with this code:

```
ByteBuffer byteContent = new ByteBuffer() ;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Page> page : pages.entrySet()) {
       byteContent.append(page.getValue().getPageData());
    }
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(book.getName() + modification + FORMAT));
    byte[] df = byteContent.toByteArray();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteContent.toByteArray()));
    com.itextpdf.layout.Document itextDocument = new com.itextpdf.layout.Document(new PdfDocument(reader, writer));
    itextDocument.close();
```

Why is there such a difference in size?
And why the files and pages, and both the `byte[]` to create the file?

Comment: Explain "Why are there such a difference in size?" Does the size increase or decrease? What are you trying to achieve? This post doesn't qualify as a question. It is very hard to understand what is asked here.

Comment: I need to save the file page by page that would then create a new file. In this example, I load a file consisting of one page. My main question is whether I save the page (maybe there is another way)? Because when you create a file of bytes save a page file can not be read

Comment: *I need to save the file page by page:* in other words, you want to *burst* a PDF file? Is that correct? Your main question is *whether I save the page*. I don't understand the part *whether I save the page.* That's not a full sentence in English. Your comment also don't explain anything about the file size. Did you read part 1 of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37131779/1622493

Comment: thanks for the link above. Yes, I need to "burst" the document. I need save pages in arrays and then bild the document from the pages of various documents.

Comment: In that case, you will indeed end up with files that are larger than you expect for the reasons explained in my answer to the question [Why does combining PDFs make filesize balloon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123352) Should I close the question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your *size* question:

> ```
> byte[] in = pdfData.getBytes(); // size file 88747
> ...
> byte[] transform = pdfDocument.getPage(1).getContentBytes(); // 1907 size page
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Why are there such a difference in size?

Because `PdfPage.getContentBytes()` does not return what you expect.

You seem to expect it to return a complete representation of the contents of the given page, and the Javadocs of that method might be interpreted (*"Get decoded bytes for the whole page content."*) to mean that.

This is not the case. `PdfPage.getContentBytes()` returns the contents of the *content stream(s)* of the page. These content stream(s) contain a sequence of commands which build the page. But these commands take parameters which *reference data outside the content stream*, e.g.:

- when text is drawn on a PDF page, the content stream contains an operation selecting a font but the data describing the font and in case of embedded fonts the font program itself are outside the content stream;
- when bitmap images are drawn, the content stream usually contains an operation for it which references image data outside the content stream;
- there are operations which reference so called xobjects which essentially are independent content streams which can be called upon from any page; these xobject are not contained in the page content stream either.

Furthermore there are annotations (e.g. form fields) with their own content streams which are stored in separate structures. And lots of page properties are outside, too.

Thus, *there are such differences in size* because you get only a minute part of the page definition using `getContentBytes`.

---

Now let's look at your code "restoring the file".

As a corollary of the above it is obvious that your code merely concatenates some content streams but does not provide the external resources these streams refer to.

But aside from that your code also points out a misunderstanding concerning the nature of PDF pages: they are not merely blobs you can split and concatenate again as you want. They are collections of PDF objects which are spread throughout the PDF file; different pages can share some of their objects (e.g. fonts of often used images).

---

What you can do instead...

As representations of a single page you should use a PDF containing the data referenced by that single page. The iText example [Burst.java](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/book/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part2/chapter06/Listing_06_23_Burst.java) shows how to do that.

To join these single page PDFs again you can use an iText `PdfMerger`. Remember to set smart mode (`PdfWriter.setSmartMode(true)`) to prevent resource duplication in the result.